# Angular 1.5 routing(ngRoute) refresh/reload issue in MVC 5

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've been going through a lot of the posts about routing mvc/angular how to use it together but still was not able to make it work.
I have problem with the page refresh/reload when being on the angular view/route, it's just wont work.

Here is what I got so far:

Anguar Route Provider - routes to my components:

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/angular/test1', {
                template: '<sample-component1></sample-component1>'
            })
            .when('/angular/test2', {
                template: '<sample-component2></sample-component2>'
            });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

MVC Web config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^(?!.*angular/).*$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

My MVC routes configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "angular",
                url: "angular/{*catch-all}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Angular" }
                );
   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults:new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Currently when I refresh page I'm getting redirected to the default route, additionally the layout is messed up even though the references seems to be in place...

What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are just allowing files from `angular` folder only. I'd say change your condition would fix the issue.

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

Comment: It does not make any difference...tested.

Comment: @MaximHash do you have `<base href="/">` tag on index.html

Comment: I have it in my layout file.

Comment: Also when refreshing my angular page I'm being redirected to Home/Index, I'm not sure why is it happening... does it mean my pattern doesn't match?

Comment: @MaximHash May i know why you have `url: "angular/{*catch-all}",` MapRoute there?

Comment: I thought that is the way to serve all the angular routes/urls ?

Comment: @MaximHash how?

Comment: I'm using "angular/" for all my angular routes definition, so I could recognize them, is it wrong?

Comment: @MaximHash I don't think so `name: "angular",` MapRoute needed at all, what you have index page in `base` tag?

Comment: You are saying i don't need "angular" MapRoute...? my base tag is <base href="/">. Since this request should be processed by the client side, does it mean I have to created another layout specifically for that?

Comment: Also since I'm using angular component approach, where I embed them on the razor pages, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Limit your `Default` route to the `Home` controller by specifying a `constraint` and then the `catch-all` route will start to work.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = "Home" } // for catch all to work
);

// Route override to work with Angularjs and HTML5 routing
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NotFound",
    url: "{*catchall}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was like this :

1. MVC routing

> ```
> routes.MapRoute(
>               name: "Application",
>               url: "{*url}",
>             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
> ```

2. Angular routing

> ```
>    $routeProvider.     
>             when("/App/", {
>                 templateUrl: scriptPath + "A.html?v=1.6",
>                 controller: "AController"
>             })
>             . when("/App/home", {
>                 templateUrl: scriptPath + "A.html?v=1.0",
>                 controller: "AController"
>             })
>             .when("/App/B", {
>                 templateUrl: scriptPath + "B.html?v=1.0",
>                 controller: "BController"
>             })
>            .when("/App/C", {
>                 templateUrl: scriptPath + "C.html?v=1.0",
>                 controller: "CController"
>             })
>             .otherwise({ redirectTo: '//App/home'});
>
>
>         $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
> ```

this section I put in app.js and loaded with _Layout.cshtml so I can have it on every page that will use the same layout.

So to fix server reload issue I just create the corresponding controllers (A,B,C) with default action (index) and returned empty view that use _Layout.cshtml

so when user click on links and moving around with angular the URL will be changed in the way that mvc will understand and if user click on Refresh button it will load the page that will load angular routing and continue with it .

All other solution that I found were suggested to change web config and put rewrite rule or put it on IIS and neither of that was acceptable for me.

i hope it will work for you...